# grunt serve removes yeoman generator-angular app dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I've been around in circles trying to figure this one out. So I've been trucking along with this project for some time now with no issues. I've made plenty of yo angular commands to scaffold out directives, controllers, views, etc. No issues. Then one day, I ran grunt serve:[target] and it blew away my last directive I made. Here is the strange thing. If I manually add it while its watching, it keeps removing it. I remove all dependencies between the build:js blocks in my index.html file and it adds all of them back except for the one(s) I've noticed. (As a side note, there were some others that I didnt catch till I started digging. They happened to be controllers) This gets even stranger. So If I add the dependency back and run grunt serve:dist, it's there. But I have to add it back first and not run grunt serve:[target], otherwise grunt serve blows it away.

So here is what I have done since noticing this bug. I've updated yeoman, generator, which required a nodejs and npm update as well. I also went through several other grunt tools in which I thought could be related, and updated all of those as well. Tools such as watch, ngmin, copy, etc.

As one other side note, I have tested to see if this is just on my computer or on others as well. And it does occur on others. They are all of various versions of OSX, yeoman, generator-angular, nodejs and npm.

Here is my Gruntfile

```js
// Generated on 2015-02-12 using generator-angular 0.10.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

 // Load grunt tasks automatically
 require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

 // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
 require('time-grunt')(grunt);

 // Configurable paths for the application
 var appConfig = {
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  dist: 'dist'
 };

 // Define the configuration for all the tasks
 grunt.initConfig({

  // Project settings
  yeoman: appConfig,

  // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
  watch: {
   bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
   },
   js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
     livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
   },
   jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
   },
   compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
   },
   gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
   },
   livereload: {
    options: {
     livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
     '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
     '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
     '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
   }
  },

  // The actual grunt server settings
  connect: {
   options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
   },
   livereload: {
    options: {
     open: true,
     middleware: function (connect) {
      return [
       connect.static('.tmp'),
       connect().use(
        '/bower_components',
        connect.static('./bower_components')
       ),
       connect.static(appConfig.app)
      ];
     }
    }
   },
   test: {
    options: {
     port: 9001,
     middleware: function (connect) {
      return [
       connect.static('.tmp'),
       connect.static('test'),
       connect().use(
        '/bower_components',
        connect.static('./bower_components')
       ),
       connect.static(appConfig.app)
      ];
     }
    }
   },
   dist: {
    options: {
     open: true,
     base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
   }
  },

  // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
  jshint: {
   options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
   },
   all: {
    src: [
     'Gruntfile.js',
     '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
   },
   test: {
    options: {
     jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
   }
  },

  // Empties folders to start fresh
  clean: {
   dist: {
    files: [{
     dot: true,
     src: [
      '.tmp',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
      '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
     ]
    }]
   },
   server: '.tmp'
  },

  // Add vendor prefixed styles
  autoprefixer: {
   options: {
    browsers: ['last 1 version']
   },
   dist: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
     src: '{,*/}*.css',
     dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
   }
  },

  // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
  wiredep: {
   app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
   },
   sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
   }
  },

  // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
  compass: {
   options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n',
    sourcemap: true
   },
   dist: {
    options: {
     generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
   },
   server: {
    options: {
     debugInfo: true
    }
   }
  },

  // Renames files for browser caching purposes
  filerev: {
   dist: {
    src: [
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
   }
  },

  // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
  // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
  // additional tasks can operate on them
  useminPrepare: {
   html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
   options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
     html: {
      steps: {
       js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
       css: ['cssmin']
      },
      post: {}
     }
    }
   }
  },

  // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
  usemin: {
   html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
   css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
   options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
   }
  },

  // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
  // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
  // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
  // to use the Usemin blocks.
  // cssmin: {
  //   dist: {
  //     files: {
  //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
  //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
  //       ]
  //     }
  //   }
  // },
  // uglify: {
  //   dist: {
  //     files: {
  //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
  //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
  //       ]
  //     }
  //   }
  // },
  // concat: {
  //   dist: {}
  // },

  imagemin: {
   dist: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
     src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
   }
  },

  svgmin: {
   dist: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
     src: '{,*/}*.svg',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
   }
  },

  htmlmin: {
   dist: {
    options: {
     collapseWhitespace: true,
     conservativeCollapse: true,
     collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
     removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
     removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
     src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
   }
  },

  // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
  // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
  ngAnnotate: {
   dist: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
     src: ['*.js', '!oldieshim.js'],
     dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
   }
  },

  // Replace Google CDN references
  cdnify: {
   dist: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
   }
  },

  // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
  copy: {
   dist: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     dot: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
     src: [
      '*.{ico,png,txt}',
      '.htaccess',
      '*.html',
      'views/{,*/}*.html',
      'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
      'fonts/{,*/}*.*'
     ]
    }, {
     expand: true,
     cwd: '.tmp/images',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
     src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
     expand: true,
     cwd: '.',
     src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }, {
     expand: true,
     cwd: 'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts',
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts',
     src: './**'
    }]
   },
   styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
   }
  },

  // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
  concurrent: {
   server: [
    'compass:server'
   ],
   test: [
    'compass'
   ],
   dist: [
    'compass:dist',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin'
   ]
  },

  // Test settings
  karma: {
   unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
   }
  },

  // Bump
  bump: {
   options: {
    files: [
     'package.json'
     , 'bower.json'
    ]
    , updateConfigs: []
    // , commit: true
    // , commitMessage: 'Release v%VERSION%'
    // , commitFiles: [
    //  'package.json'
    //  , 'bower.json'
    // ]
    // , createTag: true
    // , tagName: 'v%VERSION%'
    // , tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%'
    // , push: true
    // , pushTo: 'upstream'
    , gitDescribeOptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d'
    , globalReplace: false
   }
  },

  ngconstant: {
   options: {
    space: '  ',
    wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
    name: 'config',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/config.js'
   },
   // Environment targets
   dev: {
    constants: {
     ENV: 'development',
     debug: true,
     API_URL: 'https://some-api.staging.example.com',
     AUTH_URL: 'https://auth.staging.example.com',
     GD_API: 'https://bi.example.com'
    }
   },
   production: {
    constants: {
     ENV: 'production',
     debug: false,
     API_URL: 'https://some-api.example.com',
     AUTH_URL: 'https://auth.example.com',
     GD_API: 'https://bi.example.com'
    }
   },
   staging: {
    constants: {
     ENV: 'staging',
     debug: false,
     API_URL: 'https://some-api.staging.example.com',
     AUTH_URL: 'https://auth.staging.example.com',
     GD_API: 'https://bi.example.com'
    }
   }
  },

  // Git Hook for Bumping version on each push/pre-commit
  githooks: {
   all: {
    options: {
     template: 'hooks/pre-commit.js'
    },
    'pre-commit': 'bump'
   }
  },

  template: {
   'process-html-template': {
    options: {
     data: {
      version: appConfig.version,
      date: new Date()
     }
    },
    files: {
     'app/index.html': ['app/index.html.tpl']
    }
   }
  }
 });


 grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
  if(target === 'dist')
   return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);

  if(target === 'dist2')
   return grunt.task.run(['build:staging', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);

  if(!target)
   target = 'staging'

  grunt.task.run([
   'clean:server',
   'ngconstant:' + target,
   'wiredep',
   'concurrent:server',
   'autoprefixer',
   'connect:livereload',
   'template',
   'watch'
  ]);
 });

 grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
  grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
  grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
 });

 grunt.registerTask('test', [
  'clean:server',
  'concurrent:test',
  'autoprefixer',
  'connect:test',
  'karma'
 ]);

 grunt.registerTask('build', function(target){
  target = target || 'production'
  grunt.task.run([
   'clean:dist',
   'ngconstant:' + target,
   'wiredep',
   'useminPrepare',
   'concurrent:dist',
   'autoprefixer',
   'concat',
   'ngAnnotate',
   'copy:dist',
   'cdnify',
   'cssmin',
   'uglify',
   'filerev',
   'usemin',
   'htmlmin'
  ]);
 });

 grunt.registerTask('default', [
  'newer:jshint',
  'test',
  'build'
 ]);
};
```

Here is my index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="version" content=" - Thu Feb 12 2015 11:25:22 GMT-0800 (PST)">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ticker.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
 </head>
 <body
  ng-app="app"
  ng-controller="GlobalCtrl"
  ng-class="{blueBg: state.includes('home')}"
 >
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div class="container">

   <header
    id="header"
    ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"
    ng-include="'views/header.html'"
    class="navbar-fixed-top"
   >
   </header>

   <div
    ui-view=""
    id="content"
    class="view-animate"
   >
   </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
   <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
  </script>

  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
  <script
  src="bower_components/venturocket-angular-slider/build/angular-slider.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angucomplete/angucomplete.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/prefixfree/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/numeral/numeral.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ui-router-extras/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-logex/dist/log-ex-unobtrusive.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquerykeyframes/jquery.keyframes.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/config.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/home.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/navigation.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/global.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/filters/capitalize.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/filters/currencyabbr.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/campaigns.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/performance.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/audience.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/user.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/gooddata.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/polaris_campaign.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiences.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/country.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/industry.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/pagefilter.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/lib/top5.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/lib/tooltip.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/top5chart.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/ticker.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/funnel.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/spinner.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/summary.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/mostactive.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/trend.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/helper.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/header.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/navigation.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencesedit.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencescreate.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audienceslist.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/modal.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/locations.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/paginator.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/audienceservice.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencescreateexisting.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencescreateexistinglist.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencescreateexistingedit.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencescreatecustom.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencesupload.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/campaign.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/modal.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/spinner.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/directives/spinner.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/audiencemodal.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.4.7",
  "description": "Description",
  "author": "John Smith <jsmith@company.com>",
  "contributors": [
   {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "jsmith@company.com"
   }
  ],
  "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/Demandbase/app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ui-router": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "execSync": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "2.2.*",
    "grunt-bump": "0.0.16",
    "grunt-concurrent": "1.0.*",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.*",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.7.*",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.*",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.4.*",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.*",
    "grunt-filerev": "2.1.*",
    "grunt-githooks": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "0.9.*",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-template": "^0.2.3",
    "grunt-usemin": "3.0.*",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.*",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.24",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.*",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is all my versions (keep in mind, tested on various versions on others computers and all the same results)
Node: v0.12.0 (tested on v0.11.*, same result)
npm: 2.5.1
Yeoman: 1.4.5 (though I had the same issue on 1.3.3 as well)
generator-angular: 0.11.1 (it's been updated, didn't catch the previous version before updating)
OSX: 10.10 (also happens on 10.9.4)

Please help, I'm so stumped and my project has sort of come to a stop until I can add more dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a feature of yeoman : **wiredep** .

It keeps the dependecies of bower.json in sync with what is between the `<!-- bower:js --> <!-- endbower -->` and `<!-- bower:css --> <!-- endbower -->`

Remove those special tags or disable the **wiredep** task from the serve command at the end of the gruntfile for a quick fix.

Another option is to actually use wiredep to manage your dependencies, just tell bower to save what you install, like

```
bower install angular --save
```

and it will add it to the bower.json file, and grunt serve will put it in index.html, magic !

Comment: Thanks for following up. Yeah I suspected it to be that as well. Though it is not in the bower block. It's in my actual app/scripts part. All of my bower dependencies are being injected just fine. I've removed them and tested it without any bower dependencies and its still the same result. But good catch.

I have since then done some more testing on certain grunt tools and I think I have found the issue. It appears it could be related to grunt-template. I am still testing this though. I will follow up with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it was the grunt template. It writes to the index.html from the index.tpl.html and the dependencies where not in there. I am not sure how I have carried on this long with it working just fine up to this point. But I've tested by excluding this template step and it works just fine. It's not critical I have this step for now. Plus there are dozens of other easy solutions. I'll implement in a new way to achieve this later. For now just removing template task and moving on. Thanks Renan for your help earlier.